# Laravel pagination setpath and appends

Tags: laravel, pagination

I am stuck with Laravel Pagination. The url in the pagination always contains 2 questionmarks.

http://domain.com/?direction=asc?page=2

```
$posts = Post::paginate(10)
        ->setPath(route('post-admin', [
            'direction' => $direction
          ]))
```

In the view:

```
{!! $post->render() !!}
```

I've also tried:

```
{!! $post->appends([
    'direction' => $direction
])->render() !!}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
$posts = Post::paginate(10)
        ->setPath(route('post-admin'))
        ->appends('direction', $direction);
```

Then in your view:

```
{!! $posts->render() !!}
```

Make sure that you do not call the `all()` method, but directly call `paginate()` on the model.